# Одновременное использование tax_query и meta_query

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь реализовать поиск с учетом произвольных полей и таксономий.
Цикл работает, только когда фильтр идет только по одному из критериев (таксономия/мета-поле).
Если запустить весь, то выводит только в результатах лишь один термин таксономии property-type, независимо от условий.

```
<?php 
  $property_city = $_GET['property-city'];
  $property_type = $_GET['property-type'];
  }
  $min_price = $_GET['min-price'];
  if($min_price == ''){
    $min_price = '0';
  }
  $max_price = $_GET['max-price'];
  if($max_price == ''){
    $max_price = '99999999';
  }
  $min_size = $_GET['min-size'];
  if($min_size == ''){
    $min_size = '0';
  }
  $max_size = $_GET['max-size'];
  if($max_size == ''){
    $max_size = '999999';
  }
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
      // 'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'property-type',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $property_type,
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'property-city',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $property_city,
      ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(  
      // 'relation' => 'AND',
      array(  
        'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_price',  
        'value' => array( $min_price, $max_price ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'  
      ),
      array(  
        'key' => 'REAL_HOMES_property_size',  
        'value' => array( $min_size, $max_size ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'  
      )
    ) 
  );
  query_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: relation = or. Вот и весь секрет

Comment: А если необходимо использовать значение "AND"?
Короче, понял, в чем причина такого поведения цикла.
Так происходит потому, что не у всех записей в этом цикле заполнено поле 'REAL_HOMES_property_size'.
Пришлось пока отключить фильтр по площади.
Буду искать решение дальше...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы дружили, нужно в запрос таксономый, меты и в общем(таксономия+мета) добавить отношения AND везде. Далее, везде где сравниваются цены или площадь с `BETWEEN` установить `'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)'`, так как скорее всего сравнивает символьное значение а не цифровое, раз было подобное, когда с `'type' => 'numeric'` не работало.